# PowerBI Embedded - Unable to delete datasets

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi

I have been trying out the new PowerBI Embedded and I was sucessfully able to create a workspace collection, add some workspaces and then import my pbix and have it display.  However I now want to clean up those workspaces and remove all of the sample reports and datasets.  When I try and use the various "DeleteDataset" methods available on from Microsoft.PowerBI.Api nuget package.

If I try and delete a dataset using:

```
    var devToken = PowerBIToken.CreateDevToken(this.workspaceCollection, this.workspaceId);
using (var client = this.CreatePowerBIClient(devToken))
{
var delete_resp = client.Datasets.DeleteDatasetById(this.workspaceCollection, workspaceId, dsid);
}
```

By doing it this way I get an Unauthorized response.  I also noticed that I can create a "ProvisionToken" so doing it this way:

```
var provToken = PowerBIToken.CreateProvisionToken(this.workspaceCollection);
using (var provClient = this.CreatePowerBIClient(provToken))
{
    var delete_resp = provClient.Datasets.DeleteDatasetById(this.workspaceCollection, workspaceId, dsid);
}
```

When I use the Provision token I get an internal server error.

I understand there is dependencies between datasets and reports however I do not see any methods available to delete reports first then clean up the datasets so I was hoping since I only saw delete data set methods it would remove the report as well.  Has anyone run into these issues?  Has anyone been able to successfully delete datasets and/or remove everything from a powerbi embedded workspace?  I have been using the [sample powerbi embedded app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/) to test out these use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the datasets will also delete the reports that are connected to it. There is a bug in delete dataset that should be fixed sometime today.

Comment: I am also getting an internal server error when I attempt to import the same pbix/dataset and use the "overwrite" flag.  Is this also a known issue that will be included with the latest fixes?

Comment: I am still seeing the same errors Unauthorized and Internal Server Error as I stated above.  Has the fixed been deployed?  Thanks.

Comment: Which type of token are you using when making the delete call?

Comment: I have tried provision token and dev token.  I get the errors as stated above in my original post.

Comment: Got a repro. We are looking into it.

Comment: Verified today that I am able to delete datasets now.